# Is there a name analogous to "equivalence class" for a binary relation that is not transitive?

Tags: terminology, relations

If $R$ is a non-transitive binary relation on a set $S$, is there a name for the members of $F \subseteq power(S)$ where:

1. $f \in F \text{ and }a,b \in f\ \Rightarrow\ \langle a,b \rangle\, \in R$
2. $\bigcup_{f \in F} f = S$
3. $f1, f2 \in F \text{ and } f1 \subseteq f2 \Rightarrow f1 = f2$

Comment: I don't think so: transivity is essential to show having an equivalence relation on a set $S$ is the same as having a partition of $S$.

Comment: Thanks. I realize that $F$ is not a partition, as its members are not, in general, disjoint. There still might (perhaps) be a commonly used name.

Comment: Unless I'm reading your first two conditions incorrectly, I think such an $F$ need not exist   when $R$ is very asymmetric or not reflexive. Did you mean to assume $R$ is symmetric and reflexive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A relation $R$ on a set $S$ that is reflexive and symmetric but not necessarily transitive is called a "[tolerance relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolerance_relation)" and makes $(S,R)$ a "tolerance space". Sets that satisfy condition 1 in the OP are ($R$-)[preclasses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_sets#Tolerance_classes_and_preclasses). The maximal ones are ($R$-)classes and they satisfy condition 3 automatically. Together, they together satisfy condition 2.

There are many papers discussing tolerance spaces, but for the classes, Wikipedia cites [Tolerance spaces: Origins, theoretical aspects and applications](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ins.2012.01.023) by Peters and Wasilewski.

---

If the intention was not to assume that $R$ is reflexive, then conditions 1 and 2 may not be satisfied together if $S$ is nonempty. If the intention was to assume reflexivity but not symmetry, then condition 1 forces each $f$ to have a sort of symmetric piece of $S$, and those need not cover $S$ so condition 2 need not be compatible with condition 1.

Comment: Thanks for this info. The actual relation I am working with is symmetric but not reflexive (so I should add the rider $a \neq b$ to my condition 1). I guess this doesn't then qualify as a tolerance relation.

Comment: @AshleyMcNeile then "the classes of (the tolerance relation that is) the reflexive closure of my relation", I guess. Or "analogously to tolerance relations, we define the classes..."

Comment: I got that wrong:  the actual relation I am working with is both symmetric and reflexive, so it is a tolerance relation. Thanks for the help.